# Which way of event handling is better for performance reasons in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To set one event handler on parent element?
#1:

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const parentEventHandler = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    const divId = parseInt((event.target as HTMLElement).id);
    if (isNaN(divId)) return;
    setIndex(divId);
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={parentEventHandler}>
      <div id={'0'}></div>
      <div id={'1'}></div>
      <div id={'2'}></div>
      <div id={'3'}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or to set event handler for each child element?
#2:

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setIndex(0)}></div>
      <div onClick={() => setIndex(1)}></div>
      <div onClick={() => setIndex(2)}></div>
      <div onClick={() => setIndex(3)}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Which way of handling should I choose for better performance in React? #1 or #2?

Comment: For performance? Absolutely irrelevant, unless this happens to be in an extremely tight loop

Comment: React already use event delegation. You don't have to do it yourself

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, so it means the only difference here is that on every render we create 4 functions in #2 and 1 function in #1. But I guess function creation doesn't consume much resources, so it doesn't make a difference, right?

Comment: Right. Its absolutely insignificant to an extreme degree. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not important regardless. Some might say technically the number 1 example would be "quicker" because it it is not creating callback functions on each render for each item. This would be wrong since the contents of the handler in #1 like `parseInt`, the ID property access and `isNan` check would make actual interaction "slower".

But what you are talking about is nanoseconds. So the significantly decreased readability of that #1 example is what you really need to think about. It would be an extremely odd choice to bin the readability of your code for something which is far far less (several orders of magnitude) recognizable than a human being's perception.

Use option 2.

Answer (score 1):

i think this little article could help answering your question https://dev.to/maddevs/a-bit-about-event-delegation-in-react-4jeo